# hide and show divs with change image

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

I'm very new to `Javascript`, `html` and all that stuff and I need to help to improve what I have done so far.

I'm trying to build a page that include 4 images (acting as buttons) and 4 divs with data. All 4 divs are set to display none on startup. Each buttons are used to show one of the divs at a time. That part works well.

However, I have alternate versions of the image buttons that I want to display when a div is set to `display : block`.

Here is the javascript and html code that i have so far.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
     var divState = {}
     function showHide(id) {
         if (document.getElementById) {
            var divid = document.getElementById(id);
            divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true;

            for (var  div  in divState) {
               if (divState[div] && div !=id){
                   document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
                   divState[div] = false ;
               }
            }
         divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
        }
     }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "lob">
    <div id = "auto">
        <img src = "/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/Jeep_v2.png" alt = "Experts auto";
            onmouseover = "this.src = '/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/Auto_TXT.png'";
            onmouseout = "this.src = '/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/Jeep_v2.png'";
            onclick = "showHide('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3')";
            width = 175px; />
    </div>

<div id = "habitation">
        <img src = "/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/House_v4.png" alt = "Experts habitation";
            onmouseover = "this.src = '/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/Habit_txt.png'";
            onmouseout = "this.src = '/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/House_v4.png'";
            onclick = "showHide('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4')";
            width = 175px; />
    </div>

    <div id = "route">
        <img src = "/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/Road_v1.png" alt = "Experts route";
            onmouseover = "this.src = '/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/Route_TXT.png'";
            onmouseout = "this.src = '/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/Road_v1.png'";
            onclick = "showHide('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5')";
            width = 175px; />
    </div>

    <div id = "tous">
        <img src = "/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/All.png" alt = "Tous les experts";
            onmouseover = "this.src = '/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/Tous_TXT.png'";
            onmouseout = "this.src = '/intact/formindem/SiteAssets/LOB/All.png'";
            onclick = "showHide('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6')";
            width = 175px; />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fred,

I see what you're trying to do here. Have you considered doing this using CSS instead of JavaScript? This is the kind of thing CSS was intended for, and while JS can do it, it would be more complex (and slower, which may be noticeable on slower mobile browsers).

Something like:

```
#route {
    background-image: url("your-image-here.png");
    background-size: contain;
}

#route:hover {
    background-image: url("your-mouseover-image-here.png");
}
```

Also, it seems odd to me that you want something to be displayed differently when its container is set to `display: block`. What are you trying to achieve with that? There is likely to be a better solution available to achieve that effect.

Comment: Yes, I have 4 divs that are set to display: none on startup. When I click one of the image, the associated div appears. When I click on another images, the div called earlier disappears and the div associated with the selected button appears. I'm trying to figure out how to modify the javascript function to change the images that I clicked at the same time. Keeping in mind that it needs to come back to it's original state if I click on another one.